# FFT over only the 3rd dimension of a 3D array

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I have a C-style array with 3 dimensions and want to do an FFT over the 3rd dimension, but not over the first and second. I know, by reordering the array this should not be a problem, but does the FFTW library provide a function for this?

The array I use is:

```
int[dim1 * dim2 * dim3]
```

e.g. {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} where all dimensions have the size 3.

Now I want to make a fft over all ones, all twos, all threes etc.

In my code:

```
auto data = new int16_t[32 * NR_ROWS * NR_COLS];
```

Comment: A C-style array with 3 dimensions could be continuous in memory, when declared statically, or not, when allocated dynamically. If you include minimal code your question will be unambiguous.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I inclued an example, hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: As an intermediate step, to see later if more sophisticated solutions work, you could just extract the values you need into a ``std::vector<float>`` and use that. Later, you can compare the results to the result of a more "clever" solution.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you do. You now say `int[dim1 * dim2 * dim3]` but also `int[dim3][dim2][dim1]`. For a non-static array, these can be very different. It's about data locality. If the data is contiguous, then FFTW has a function in the Guru interface where you can apply a "strided" FFT directly to the data. If it's not contiguous, the only option is to copy the data over. Please, show an actual C code snippet where you allocate the array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, guru could help me maybe, I will try it!

Comment: This is the function I was thinking of: [`fftw_plan_many_dft `](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) -- there's a real-to-complex variant as well. You'll have `howmany=9` transforms, with `istride=9` and a `idist=1`. See the last example on the linked documentation page.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you very much!